# ASP.NET MVC Basic Authentication Counting Attempts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, .net-4.0, routes

ASP.NET MVC 3 on VS 2010, .NET Framework 4:

I have a web.config set to "none" for authentication. I have some custom attributes and code that enables Basic Authentication (based on what I already found here from the gurus - thanks). After 3 failed attempts, IIS displays its own "auth denied" message. I am trying to change the count to 5 attempts and display my own error page. So far I can't see how to do this.

An excerpt from the auth class:

```
CustomBasicAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
...
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    if (!Authenticate(filterContext.HttpContext))
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpCustomBasicUnauthorizedResult();
    }
    else
    {
        if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            HttpCachePolicyBase cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
            cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
            cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, null /* data */);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary
                    {
                            { "client", filterContext.RouteData.Values[ "client" ] },
                            { "controller", "Account" },
                            { "action", "Login" },
                            { "ReturnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }
                    } );

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have shown only part of your code and this part has no relevance to the counting of unsuccessful authentication attempts. You haven't shown for example how the Authenticate and AuthorizeCore methods look like.

Comment: I do not have any counting code in there yet because I think this is where the counting should occur, but am not sure. I put in breakpoints all over this code and have explored the properties/events/methods in the debugger at runtime are not showing me anything.

Answer (score 0):

Its not IIS displaying this, your browser is, thus can't be changed. Load up fiddler and you should be able to confirm the 4th request is never sent out from your browser and the 3rd request's response from IIS is not the page you are seeing.

Comment: I am still trying to get clue... If this was Forms auth then I could know when a user was rejected finally and show a particular page. I was thinking with Basic I could "accept" rejected credentials on the 3rd try and redirect them to a Unauthorized User page and clear the logon history so a user could return later and try to authenticate again.